# Working with huge text files in PHP?

Tags: php, file, large-files, text-files

I need to scan through a 30MB text file - it's a list of world cities - How can I access this file, I feel like a File_Get_Contents will give my server a stroke

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822165/php-read-large-text-file-log

Comment: 30mb isn't huge.  I've processed 4gb files with PHP before.  It's possible...

Comment: Did you actually try `file_get_contents`?

Answer (score 7):

Just [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) it and then use [`fgets`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).

Answer (score 1):

[Filesystem functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) come handy in this situation.

### Example

```
$filename = "your_file_path";

// to open file
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r'); // use 'rw' to open file in read/write mode

// to output entire file
echo fread($fp, filesize($filename));

// to close file
fclose($fp);
```

---

### References

(some handy functions)

- [All Filesystem Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)
- [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) - open file
- [fread()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) - read file content
- [fgets()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) - to get line
- [fwrite()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) - write content to file
- [fseek()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) - change file pointer's position
- [rewind()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) - rewind file pointer to pos 0
- [fclose()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) - close file
- ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$fh = @fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($fh) {
    while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== false) {
        echo $line;
        // do something with $line..
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

More information/examples on http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Comment: yet another case where the '@' operator is not only useless, but even harmfull ;)

Comment: worth mentioning why: the **@** operator will disable any error reporting even severe ones, file not found, permissions and so on, and could make hard the debug process. Also the complementary else could come in handy.