# processing big text files in PHP

Tags: php, large-files

How to process big text file in PHP?
In python one can use generators and read file just line by line without loading whole file to memory. Is there something like generators in PHP?

Comment: if you search on SO you'll find this question answered many times capoluca, i've flagged your question as a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822165/php-read-large-text-file-log  read it and you'll understand how to do what you want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading very large files in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162176/reading-very-large-files-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run your php script in batch command ...

make a new file (run.bat)
right click and edit
and put this in the file :

```
c:/PHP/php.exe -f .\yourscript.php
```

change the url to `php.exe` and to yourscript.php to where its located 
then loop true the file with this :

```
<?php
$data=file("the big file.txt");
$lines=count($data);

$x=0;
while($x<=$lines){

print $data[$x]."\n";

sleep(1); //print out new line every 1 sec 

$x++;}
```