# Remove duplicate data in a text file with php

Tags: php

I am in need to open a text file (file.txt) which contains data in the following format

```
ai
bt
bt
gh
ai
gh
lo
ki
ki
lo
```

ultimately I want to remove all the duplicate lines so only one of each data remains. So the result would look like this

```
ai
bt
gh
lo
ki
```

any help with this would be awesome

Comment: `$unique = array_unique(explode("\n", file_get_contents('file.txt')));`

Comment: @nkamm please do not use comments to post solutions.  Please delete your above comment.

Comment: @nkamm One Liner Love it!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$lines = file('file.txt');
$lines = array_unique($lines);
```

[`file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) reads the file and puts every line in an array.

[`array_unique()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) removes duplicate elements from the array.

Also, to put everything back into the file:

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', implode($lines));
```

Comment: that did the trick, but it left a blank line between each one. Is there a way to remove the blank lines?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot that `file()` doesn't remove newline characters. Answer updated. :)

Comment: I have a 100MB text file and long rows for which this code is not working. Any alternatives?

Comment: @ArushKamboj Maybe checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822165/php-read-large-text-file-log

Answer (score 2):

Take the php [function file()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file.php) to read the file. You get an array of lines from your file. After that, take [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-unique.php) to kick out the duplicates.

In the end, you will have something like

```
$lines = array_unique(file("your_file.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
$txt = implode('\n',array_unique(explode('\n', $txt)));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to this code-only answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa: $txt contains the data and `explode()` puts every line in an array (using `\n` delimiter) so we can de-duplicate with `array_unique()`. Everything is then merged back together using `implode()` and the same delimiter.

Comment: Try this instead: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29171605/edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$lines = explode('\n', $lines);
$lines = array_unique($lines);
$lines = implode('\n', $lines);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $lines);
```

Comment: Your answer is in the Review Queue for being low quality and may be deleted.  Please add some explanation with your code-only answer so that future readers can fully benefit.  Never post code-only answers on SO.